# Compare two dataframe and output as a new folder

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I have two folder which one is my database and one is a new case.

database.

```
  preferredName_A     preferredName_B    score
0            AACS               LAMA4    0.467
1            AACS              HMGCS1    0.954
2            AACS               ACACA    0.546
                     .
                     .
                     .
227630       MDH2               IDH3B    0.950
```

new case

```
 preferredName_A      
0           AACS                      
1          ACACA
2           MDH2
3          IDH3B
```

and I would like to use the new case to merge/compare both files.

my estimated output folder should be

```
  preferredName_A     preferredName_B    score
0            AACS               ACACA    0.546
1            MDH2               IDH3B    0.950
```

i have try this code

```
def load_database():
  pip = pd.read_csv(open('databse.tsv','r'),sep=',',index_col= False)
  return pip

file = f'newcase.tsv'
with open(file) as f:
  pip_new_case = pd.read_csc(f),sep=',',index_col=False)
new = pd.merge(load_database().astype({preferredName_A:str}),pip_new_case,on='preferredName_A',how = 'left'
print(new)
```

but from the above code, it return me more than the original database which is not my estimated output. Could I know how to change the code at the above or have any better solution.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you only want `AACS` to return a match on the row `2, AACS, ACACA, 0.546`? Why not also on index `0,1`? Do you only want to keep the last match?

Comment: what the purpose is fo filter out the same interaction. The new case have include four Name, thus I need to find is there matching to each others. `a,b``c,d` and i want it to check whether `a,b`,`a,c``a,d` all the group have matching the database or not